# Access nested object in react props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have props in my child component like so

props in child:

```
myProps = 
{
    "url": "some url",
    "child_tiers": [
        {
            "tier_type": 1,
            "child_tiers": [
                {
                    "tier_type": 2,
                    "lower": 1.0,
                    "upper": 4.0,
                    "child_tiers": [
                        {
                            "tier_type": 3,
                            "lower": 0.0,
                            "upper": 5.0,
                            "child_tiers": [
                                {
                                    "tier_type": 4,
                                    "lower": 1,
                                    "upper": 100,
                                    "values": {
                                        "lowest": 85,
                                        "highest": 95,
                                        "multiplier": 18,
                                        "tier": "deepest tier"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "tier_type": 4,
                                    "lower": 100,
                                    "upper": 200,
                                    "values": {
                                        "lowest": 185,
                                        "highest": 195,
                                        "multiplier": 118,
                                        "tier": "deepest tier"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "values": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": null
                }
            ],
            "values": null
        }
    ],
    "description": "Important Description"
}
```

These props are part of the state of the parent component (the state of the parent is being set by calling an API using fetch). I want to create 3 arrays one each for lowest, highest and multiplier values in the deepest tier.
I am able to console log `this.props.myProps.url` / `this.props.myProps.description` /
`this.props.myProps.child_tiers` but when I do `this.props.myProps.child_tiers[0]` I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.
Is there a clean way to achieve this? Can I use Promise here?
Other suggested solutions of having the state as null didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm going to make the assumption that child_tiers is undefined until the API returns a value to the state. In which case, there would be a couple solutions. One would be to have a check in place that checks for the existence of the data from the API prior to doing anything with it. If you're using a compatible transpiler and have it set up for optional chaining, then you could also do something like this this.props.myProps?.child_tiers?.[0] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could access the object with values `lowest, highest and multiplier`

```js
myProps = 
{
    "url": "some url",
    "child_tiers": [
        {
            "tier_type": 1,
            "child_tiers": [//
                {
                    "tier_type": 2,
                    "lower": 1.0,
                    "upper": 4.0,
                    "child_tiers": [//
                        {
                            "tier_type": 3,
                            "lower": 0.0,
                            "upper": 5.0,
                            "child_tiers": [//
                                {
                                    "tier_type": 4,
                                    "lower": 1,
                                    "upper": 100,
                                    "values": {
                                        "lowest": 85,
                                        "highest": 95,
                                        "multiplier": 18,
                                        "tier": "deepest tier"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "tier_type": 4,
                                    "lower": 100,
                                    "upper": 200,
                                    "values": {
                                        "lowest": 185,
                                        "highest": 195,
                                        "multiplier": 118,
                                        "tier": "deepest tier"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "values": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "values": null
                }
            ],
            "values": null
        }
    ],
    "description": "Important Description"
}

o=myProps.child_tiers[0]["child_tiers"][0]["child_tiers"][0]["child_tiers"][0].values
lowest=[{low:o.lowest}]
highest=[{hight:o.highest}]
multiplier=[{multiple:o.multiplier}]
console.log(o)
console.log(lowest,highest,multiplier)
```

Comment: React gives an error when on myProps.child_tiers[0] so I cant go beyond that.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. Going 1 level deep gives this error.

Comment: in that case it means either your data is not of the same format you posted maybe it's sightly different because it's too deeply nested you haven't noticed that or you api didn't return any data in the first place, to check the latter console.log(data)// the data you receive from the api and see if it shows any values